# More detiles in displacement of texture

Tags: subdivision-surface, 3d-printing, displacement

I want to displace a a symbol on this cube but in order to make it look good I need to add a lot of subdivison. I want this symbol to be a part of geometry since it will be used for 3d printing. Do you have a better idea how dispale a sybol with good resolution but with less geometry.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Details are directly connected to how dense geometry is. 
Make the cube dense so that it has same amount of planes as your image has pixels.
So if your Planet lets say is 32x32px, the cube should have 32x32 planes to display it without additional artifacts.